# Installing tensorflow for R with a venv python?

Tags: python, r, tensorflow, keras

**I want to install tensorflow (and Keras too) for R.**
I used thoses lines

```
install.packages("keras")
install.packages("tensorflow")

library(keras)
library(tensorflow)
```

And now I want to do :

```
install_tensorflow()
install_keras()
```

But my python environement is inconsistent. **Is there a way to told R to look for virtual python environnement ?**

Thanks

EDIT : This is the error telling me that my environment is incosistent.

```
> install_tensorflow()
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): ...working... done
Solving environment: ...working... 
The environment is inconsistent, please check the package plan carefully
The following packages are causing the inconsistency:

  - defaults/win-64::anaconda==custom=py37_1
  - defaults/win-64::bkcharts==0.2=py37_0
  - defaults/noarch::dask==2.5.2=py_0
  - defaults/noarch::ipywidgets==7.5.1=py_0
  - defaults/noarch::jupyterlab==1.2.6=pyhf63ae98_0
  - defaults/noarch::jupyterlab_server==1.1.4=py_0
  - defaults/win-64::keras==2.2.4=0
  - defaults/noarch::seaborn==0.10.1=py_0
  - defaults/win-64::statsmodels==0.10.1=py37h8c2d366_0
  - defaults/noarch::tensorboard==2.0.0=pyhb38c66f_1
  - defaults/win-64::tensorflow==1.15.0=mkl_py37h3789bd0_0
  - defaults/win-64::tensorflow-base==1.15.0=mkl_py37h190a33d_0
  - defaults/noarch::tensorflow-estimator==1.15.1=pyh2649769_0
  - defaults/win-64::widgetsnbextension==3.5.1=py37_0
  - defaults/win-64::_anaconda_depends==2019.03=py37_0
  - defaults/win-64::_ipyw_jlab_nb_ext_conf==0.1.0=py37_0
failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
```

Comment: What do you mean by "my python environement is inconsistent"?

Comment: I edited my question with the error message I have. To overcome it, I created a virtual environement. I want now to use this new virtual env when installing tensorflow for R.

Comment: Follow the instructions mentioned [here](https://tensorflow.rstudio.com/reference/tensorflow/install_tensorflow/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @TFer, I missed the envname parameters when trying the method "virtualen" before.

The solution is simply to create a new virtual env by passing thoses options in the function :

```
install_tensorflow(method="virtualenv", envname="venv-R")
```